# How can I debug a React app running inside a Vagrant VM with VS Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, vagrant, visual-studio-code

I created my app with `create-react-app`, and run it inside a VM managed by Vagrant. The sources are in the shared `/vagrant` folder and `create-react-app` claims out of the box debuggability with VS Code. I'm using VS Code on the host.

However, I'm not sure how to set my Chrome launch configuration for my use case, and no matter what I try I keep getting this message on any breakpoint I set:

> breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "/vagrant/*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where:

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
   "/vagrant/*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
}
```

is really the secret ingredient to make source maps workable for VS Code. This maps the `/vagrant/` directory that is normally the root of your project on the VM, to `${workspaceRoot}` which is the root of your project on the host, when opened as a directory in VS Code.

A very simple fix, in hindsight.